# Dependent Drop down list using javascript ASP.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

For ASPX page i have wrote

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

            function OnSelectedIndexChange_tb_type() {
                ddl = document.getElementById("<%=tb_type.ClientID %>");
                ddl1= document.getElementById("<%=tb_diagnost_by.ClientID %>");

                var options = document.createElement("option");

                if (ddl.selectedIndex == 1) {

                    ddl1.options[0] = new Option("---Select---", "0");
                    ddl1.options[1] = new Option("Sputum", "Sputum");
                    ddl1.options[2] = new Option("CX Ray", "CX Ray");
                }
                else if (ddl.selectedIndex == 2) {
                    ddl1.options[3] = new Option("---Select---", "0");
                    ddl1.options[4] = new Option("Limph node", "Limph node");
                    ddl1.options[5] = new Option("CSF", "CSF");
                    ddl1.options[6] = new Option("Plural Fluid", "Plural Fluid");
                    ddl1.options[7] = new Option("Ascitic Fluid", "Ascitic Fluid");
                    ddl1.options[8] = new Option("Urine", "Urine");
                    ddl1.options[9] = new Option("Other", "Other");
                }
                else {
                    ddl1.options[10] = new Option("---Select---", "0");
                }
            }
        </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

        function OnSelectedIndexChange_tb_diagnost_by() {

            ddl1 = document.getElementById("<%=tb_diagnost_by.ClientID %>");
            ddl2 = document.getElementById("<%=tb_diagnost_by_detail.ClientID %>");

            var options = document.createElement("option");

            if (ddl1.selectedIndex == 1) 
            {
                ddl2.options[0] = new Option("---Select---", "0");
                ddl2.options[1] = new Option("AFB", "AFB");
                ddl2.options[2] = new Option("Gene Xpert", "Gene Xpert");
            }
            else if {
                ddl2.options[3] = new Option("---Select---", "Select");
                ddl2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            else{
                 ddl2.options[4] = new Option("---Select---", "Select");
            }

         }
    </script>
```

But i am getting an error

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using pages ...

need solution. please help me out...because i am stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new options without informing the server on aspx, that is changing the viewstate, so you need to disable event validation, or use an update panel and do this from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Add event listener to your dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DD1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnClick="DD1_Click" />
```

then in your .NET page 
at the top add

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

then below page load.

```
protected void DD1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var index = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58tf9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx

now transform your javascript to .NET code. 
You could use your approach in MVC but trust me in WebForms you have set yourself straigth to Mordor.